# ImageViews and Intents

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview, android-intent

So I'm trying to start a new activity when an image is clicked that will start a new activity with the image being in full screen. To do this I've written the following code:

ImageView defined in XML file:

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/sun"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/sun_title"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:contentDescription="@string/sun_image"
     android:src="@drawable/sun" />
```

Here is where I use an onClickListener to handle the intent when the image is clicked:

```
ImageView imageView;
//begin onViewCreated Method
     ...

     final Context classContext = null;
     imageView = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.sun);

     imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent i = new Intent(classContext, Settings.class);
               startActivity(i);                
          }
     });

     ...
//end onViewCreated Method
```

I get no errors with the following code but when I run the application and tap the image, the app crashes with a nullPointerException. Here is the logcat for that:

```
02-25 16:55:43.201: E/AndroidRuntime(3459): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-25 16:55:43.201: E/AndroidRuntime(3459): Process: com.andrewq.planets, PID: 3459
02-25 16:55:43.201: E/AndroidRuntime(3459): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-25 16:55:43.201: E/AndroidRuntime(3459):     at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:77)
02-25 16:55:43.201: E/AndroidRuntime(3459):     at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3821)
02-25 16:55:43.201: E/AndroidRuntime(3459):     at com.andrewq.planets.FragmentA$2.onClick(FragmentA.java:43)
02-25 16:55:43.201: E/AndroidRuntime(3459):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
02-25 16:55:43.201: E/AndroidRuntime(3459):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
02-25 16:55:43.201: E/AndroidRuntime(3459):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-25 16:55:43.201: E/AndroidRuntime(3459):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-25 16:55:43.201: E/AndroidRuntime(3459):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-25 16:55:43.201: E/AndroidRuntime(3459):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-25 16:55:43.201: E/AndroidRuntime(3459):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 16:55:43.201: E/AndroidRuntime(3459):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-25 16:55:43.201: E/AndroidRuntime(3459):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-25 16:55:43.201: E/AndroidRuntime(3459):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-25 16:55:43.201: E/AndroidRuntime(3459):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Hope this is enough information for an answer.

Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT:** I haven't created the other activity for the image so for testing purposes, I'm having it open my preferences activity.

Comment: What if you try with this... Intent i = new Intent(actuallClass.this, Settings.class);

Comment: @geekCode - That gives me an error. It says actualClass cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: Just replace actualClass with the name of your class and the second parameter has to be the next class... and on the startActivity(i);   add this... ActualClass.this.startActivity(i); again just replace actualClass for the name of your class

Comment: @geekCode Now it says this: The constructor Intent(FragmentA, Class<Settings>) is undefined in the form of an Eclipse error.

Comment: did you add the ActualClass.this.startActivity(i); line to your code...???

Comment: @geekCode - Yes I did! But I now have a solution...that is: Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Settings.class);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have

```
final Context classContext = null;
```

so `classContext` is `null`. Since it looks like you are in a `Fragment`, try

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Settings.class);
```

Comment: even better startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),Settings.class));
Everything in 1 line :-)

Comment: @LuisAlberto yes, that should work also. But I'm not sure it is "better". I like to keep them separate in case `Extra`s (etc...) need to be add plus I like the readability better. But that is just preference.

Comment: Yeah but everything in 1 line keep the code look clean, and you're right if you want to set arguments or set some property of the intent its impossible to do it the way i did.

Comment: @LuisAlberto it does keep it all in one line. That's why I said it's dev preference. I like to have them separate but I agree it will work and just another way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `classContext` is `null`. If this code is in `Activity` then create the `Intent` like

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
```

If it is from some other class then make sure you pass the valid `Context` to that class and use it instead of `classContext` in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer...I chose codeMagic's as best however because his was easy to understand before he edited your answer. But you were both right.